# Google alerts feed not creating properly

Tags: keyword, google-alerts

I am passing following keywords string while creating alert:-
"Digital Marketing" OR "Search Engine Optimisation" OR "Social Media Management" OR Analytics OR "Content Marketing" OR "Google AdWords" OR "Google Analytcs" OR Facebook OR LinkedIn OR Twitter OR Snapchat OR "Online Marketing" OR "Internet Marketing" OR "web marketing" OR SEO OR PPC OR "Inbound Marketing" OR "Digital Media" OR "Mobile Marketing" OR "Mobile Advertising" OR "Facebook Advertising" OR "Blogging" OR "Email Marketing" OR "Youtube Advertising" OR "Local Marketing"

But it says There are no results for the query.
Once new results are published on the web they will appear here.

And also there is no mail being sent for ths alert.

What can be the reason? How can I solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one by picking a search query for Google to track for you. Next, click on Manage Alerts and hit the Edit button on an alert you want to get an RSS feed for. Under the “Deliver to” option, change the option from your email address to “Feed.” Hit the blue Save button.